# Ubuntu 20.04 Activities do not show all windows

Tags: 20.04, activities-overview

I recently upgraded to 20.04.1 LTS. Unfortunately, the super key (Activities button) does not give overview of all open windows. Instead, I just get a search bar on top of the screen and Workspaces to dock extension becomes active.
I look at few other posts on similar topic and can not find the similar case. For me it happen in any keyboard layout and I do not have some other mentioned extensions. Could someone help with with any solution for this? Thank you!